# How to change Radiobutton state in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

How can I change radiobutton state in python? I refer some examples.

I have dependency of radio buttons:

1. Option A Option B
2. Option 1 Option 2
3. Option i Option ii

By default I want only option A to be selected, and other disabled. When user selects Option B that time Option A should go disable and then Option 1, Option 2, Option i, and  Option ii activates, that means user can select these now.

How can I change the state of options and create dependency?

```
import tkinter as tk
master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Tool")
master.geometry("700x300")
var = tk.StringVar()
var.set(' ') 
def sel():
   selection =  (var.get())
   print(selection)
   if(selection==1):
       R4.config(state=["disabled"])
tk.Label(master, text="SELECT --").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=0,sticky='w')
R1 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option A", variable=var, value=1, command=sel).grid(row=2,column=1)
R2 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option B", variable=var, value=2, command=sel).grid(row=2,column=2)
R3 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=3, command=sel).grid(row=3,column=1)
R4 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=4, command=sel).grid(row=3,column=2)
R5 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option i", variable=var, value=5, command=sel).grid(row=4,column=1)
R6 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option ii", variable=var, value=6, command=sel).grid(row=4,column=2)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: *"only option A should be selected, and other disabled"* If other are disabled, how can you select *Option B*?  Also split those `R1 = tk.Radiobutton(...).grid(...)` into two lines `R1 = tk.Radiobutton(...)` and `R1.grid(...)`.

Comment: ok,,done.. but when i'm using this var.get its not working def sel():
   selection =  (var.get())
   print(selection)
   if(var.get()==1):
       R3.config(state=["disabled"])
       R4.config(state=["disabled"])
       R5.config(state=["disabled"])
       R6.config(state=["disabled"])
tk.Label(master, text="SELECT --").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=0,sticky='w')
R1 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option A", variable=var, value=1, command=sel)
R1.grid(row=2,column=1)
R2 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option B", variable=var, value=2, command=sel)
R2.grid(row=2,column=2)

Comment: It is because the value returned by `var.get()` is a string as `var` is `StringVar()`.  Either change `var` to `IntVar()` or use `selection = int(var.get())`.  Also `state=["disabled"]` should be `state="disabled"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I understood from your question, I have this:

```
import tkinter as tk
master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Tool")
master.geometry("700x300")
var = tk.StringVar()
var.set('5') 
def sel():
   selection =  (var.get())
   print(selection)
   if(selection=='1'):
       R6.config(state="disabled")
       R3.config(state="disabled")
       R5.config(state="disabled")
       R4.config(state="disabled")
   elif selection=='2':
       R1.config(state="disabled")
       R6.config(state="normal")
       R3.config(state="normal")
       R5.config(state="normal")
       R4.config(state="normal")
   else:
       R1.config(state="normal")
       R2.config(state="normal")
       R6.config(state="normal")
       R3.config(state="normal")
       R5.config(state="normal")
       R4.config(state="normal")

tk.Label(master, text="SELECT --").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=0,sticky='w')
R1 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option A", variable=var, value="1", command=sel)
R1.grid(row=2,column=1)
R2 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option B", variable=var, value="2", command=sel)
R2.grid(row=2,column=2)
R3 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option 1", variable=var, value='3', command=sel)
R3.grid(row=3,column=1)
R4 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option 2", variable=var, value='4', command=sel)
R4.grid(row=3,column=2)
R5 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option i", variable=var, value='5', command=sel)
R5.grid(row=4,column=1)
R6 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option ii", variable=var, value='6', command=sel)
R6.grid(row=4,column=2)
master.mainloop()
```